# My program has a missing operator even though the value is set previously. (batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I made a program where the user sets the value of %bet%. When %bet% is used in the file it says "Missing Operator"

```
set /p %bet=
```

this is the code to set the bet, the code below is the code that pretends %bet% doesn't exist.

```
:BJwinplayer
echo You have won!
set /a %money%=%money%+%bet%
set bet=0
echo play again?
set /p %a5= y/n
if %a5%==y goto BJBet
if %a5%==n goto CasGenerate
if %a5%==Y goto BJBet
if %a5%==N goto CasGenerate
```

Comment: I apologize if this is a simple syntax error, but I don't understand. I've tried looking at other questions but their problems were different situations.

Comment: Your `Set /p %Bet=`  should be `Set /p Bet=`  you dont need the % when setting a variable

Comment: Thank you, but it still didn't work. I can edit the full code in if you think it'll help

Comment: according to your errormessage either `%money%` or `%bet%` is not defined. Check with `echo -%money%-, -%bet%-`just before your `set /a ...`

Comment: Earlier in the program it uses %money%. Showing it is valid. The error is in this line of code: set /a %money%=%money%-%bet%
                               set bet=0

Comment: according to your errormessage either %money% or %bet% is not defined. Check with echo -%money%-, -%bet%-just before your set /a ...

Comment: I also tried your method Stephan, both are defined. But nothing seems to work.

Comment: there is no other possibility for "Missing Operator" - one of them is not defined. Please post more code.

Comment: `set /a %money%=%money%+%bet%` should be `set /a money=%money%+%bet%`, but a simple `set /a money=money+bet` also works (and a simpler `set /a money+=bet` also)...

Comment: Thank you, That fixed it. I apologize for it being a simple syntax error I couldn't figure out. I'm not too good at code.

Answer (score 0):

```
set /a %money%=%money%+%bet%
```

should be:

```
set /a money=%money%+%bet%
```

but a simple

```
set /a money=money+bet
```

also works, and a simpler

```
set /a money+=bet
```

works also...

Comment: Did you saw my answer? Solve it your problem?